# Xlsx file not able to read data in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, excel, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5.2 and "maatwebsite/excel": "~2.1.0", I am not able to read xlsx file data i am getting response empty data
My code is here

```
Excel::load($filePathNew, function($reader) {
$results = $reader-\>get();
$results = $reader-\>all();
dd($results);
});
```

Comment: What is `-\>` supposed to do?

Comment: sorry the code is $results = $reader->get();
$results = $reader->all();

Comment: ok, first `dd($filePathNew);` and where does that file come from? is it posted using a form? Does it come from the storage directory?

Comment: its come from storage

Answer (score 0):

Since you use laravel 5.. try use phpspreadsheet or latest laravel.. mean upgrade PHP.

The problem seem you need more advance PHP to read the file.. try copy the file on disk before import/read.. sometime the excel unreadable or worse

On your code.. plz added excel check.. if readable or not.. if the file is excel or not
Read bout check excel using phpexcel before assume this is xls or does or perhaps other(?)